# AndroidManifest.xml for Gradle instrumentTest

Tags: java, android, gradle

Is there a way to specify an additional `AndroidManifest.xml` file for a gradle test aplication? I need it to specify additional permissions and activities for my unit tests.

**UPD:**
I've tried to add `instrumnetTest` section in the `build.gradle` file, but it didn't help and I still get `Unable to resolve activity for: Intent` error

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    instrumentTest {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/instrumentTest/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDir 'src/instrumentTest/Java'
    }
}
```

Comment: have you been able to work this around?  I am running into this problem at the moment and am afraid there is no way to make this work because AndroidManifest.xml is automatically generated for instrumentTest: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration  It is really restrictive :(

Comment: I've managed to work around this but only by changing the Android gradle plugin itself - I don't believe this is possible to achieve without doing that.

Comment: I'd like to do this too, to override the icon and app name in the test app.  Pity it's not supported.  @ZoFreX, where did you make the change, and/or have you contacted the Google folks?

Answer (score 11):

You can specify an special `AndroidManifest.xml` for Android Tests (formerly called Instrument Tests) if you are able to use the **0.13.0** (or later) release of the Android Gradle Plugin.

Simply put the file at `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` - the manifest merger will take care of the file when you run the gradle test task.

There's an example in the official documentation ["gradle-samples-0.13.zip\gradle-samples-0.13\androidManifestInTest"](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=YW5kcm9pZC5jb218dG9vbHN8Z3g6M2U5ZGUzNTU3M2M3NDA0ZA) - as one can see there's no special configuration needed to have the test manifest included.

Answer (score 0):

I have made separate 'android-library' project for testing purposes and added all required components (Activities, Services, etc.) into ./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

According the documentation http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing-Android-Libraries

> The manifest of the Library is merged into the manifest of the test
>   app (as is the case for any project referencing this Library).

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can, in your build.gradle when you define your sourceSets, you can specify the path of your manifest :

```
 sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDir 'src/main/src'
            res.srcDir 'src/main/res'
            assets.srcDir 'src/main/assets'
            resources.srcDir 'src/main/src'
            aidl.srcDir 'src/main/src'
        }

 instrumentTest {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/instrumentTest/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDir 'src/instrumentTest/src'
            res.srcDir 'src/instrumentTest/res'
            assets.srcDir 'src/instrumentTest/assets'
            resources.srcDir 'src/instrumentTest/src'
            aidl.srcDir 'src/instrumentTest/src'
        }
}
```

you can checkout on this documentation :
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: The manifest is ignored for tests.  According to the [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration): 

> The sourceSet should not contain an AndroidManifest.xml as it is automatically generated.