# minsdk and targetsdk in Androidmanifest and build.gradle both?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have just migrated a project from Exclipse to Android Studio.
The `build.gradle` file has a section that includes:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.someone.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

The same thing is in the `uses-sdk` element of the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

When both settings are simultaneously present, which settings are respected?
Also, should I remove them from `AndroidManifest.xml`? My project must support Api-8 at least. Would it make any difference on old platforms if the `uses-sdk` section is removed from the manifest file?

Comment: You wont need the manifest min sdk and target sdk anymore.  Gradle will take care of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only need to define the min SDK and target SDK in the `build.gradle` file.  The Gradle build system will automatically define these values in the manifest when you build.

If you define them in both the `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` files, the settings in the `build.gradle` file will override the manifest ones.

Best practice is to completely remove the `<uses-sdk>` tag in the manifest and only use the `build.gradle` file to specify the min SDK and target SDK.  This will not make any difference for older devices; it will run exactly the same.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

The same thing applies for the `versionCode` and `versionName` settings.