# Android Studio:Min SDK in my project

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When I try to sync my project this message appears to me

> The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file. You can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig in the build.gradle file.

What should I do?

Comment: Don't declare the `minSdk` on the manifest and do it in the module's `build.gradle` inside `defaultConfig`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [minsdk and targetsdk in Androidmanifest and build.gradle both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234841/minsdk-and-targetsdk-in-androidmanifest-and-build-gradle-both)

Comment: i solve the problem

Comment: how to set paths to Android.mk in android studio?

Comment: kalawy, how did you solve this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795814/the-minsdk-version-should-not-be-declared-in-the-android-manifest-file