# The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play-services, google-play-games

Gradle Sync Errors are coming up on my build.gradle file for a module I imported called BaseGameUtils saying `The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file.` I don't call this at all from what I can see, and I don't in the Android Manifest either?

But [here](https://pastebin.com/giAqgkHS) is my build.gradle file. Please help!

Comment: You showed us the build.gradle file.  The error message says that the problem is in the manifest file.

Comment: @StephenC The IDE links the error to this file also there is no code written in my AndroidManifest for the minSDK. The only place where I see it is under my Merged Manifest where I cannot delete it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Inside your manifest there must be  inside which minsdkversion might have been written. Just remove `<uses-sdk>....</uses-sdk>`

Comment: This tag is not in the Android Manifest but in the Merged Manifest so I cannot delete it.

Comment: remove <uses-sdk> similarly how permission is removed on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616334/how-to-remove-specific-permission-when-build-android-app-with-gradle

Comment: the `uses-sdk` tag can also be inside a library's manifest file. for example, opencv contains this tag, so creates the problem.

Comment: @AnubhavGupta That doesn't work. I just tried. It give an error: ""tools:node" associated with an element type "uses-sdk" is not bound."

Comment: @AnubhavGupta, are there side effects if I remove this line? should I add it somewhere else (I had uses-sdk in both main manifest and in library manifest)

Comment: I've just imported an old project from Eclipse and had the same issue, this answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue when trying to use `androidx.security` on minimum SDK version 19. The `lint` command threw an exception on the `<uses-sdk>` tag.
I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175950/1651697
It turns out I didn't need to define the `android:minSdkVersion`, just override the `<uses-sdk>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

currently, I'm using openCV, my solution is to change minsdk in build.gradle for module:app and build.gradle module:OpenCVLibrary with the same version. i hope it's work for you