# how to set minSdkVersion for androidTest

Tags: android, android-testing

I have an android project and I wrote some test cases in androidTest. When I run test cases, it will generate two apk files: one is my application and another is test app. I have changed minSdkVersion in build.gradle to 18 but the minSdkVersion of test app is still 25. Could some tell me how to change the minSdkVersion for androidTest ?

Comment: show your `build.gradle` please.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a new product flavor for your tests in Android Studio and override the minSdkVersion property. Here is the documentation : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors

Also, you can take a look to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880936/7947225

Comment: yes, I have added a new flavor and set the minSdkVersion to 18. However, the produced test apk's minSdkVersion is still 25. That answer I have tried but it does work. It seems that there is a invisible AndroidManifest for androidTest